# How would you implement decrease and remove operations for items in basket?

Tags: e-commerce, market-basket-analysis

my question is pretty simple.
I am asking that because some of my colleagues and I have different views about how Decrease operation has to act.

The realization of the basket is trivial - List of items which have Quantity property.

**For my colleagues** the decrease operation cannot could only reduce the quantity until the quantity is positive and the decrease operation cannot remove items from basket. 
The decrease operation could just reduce the quantity property until the property is greater or equal to 1. So, the decrease operation cannot reach Quantity = 0 and if you want, from your front-end, to decrease one more time, you have to call remove method.

I do not understand very well this conception because you could implement Quantity as decimal, because you could sell something in portions. And the min quantity could be different.
Also, the requirements for min quantity is not related to the basket operations - it is a business rule and it could be different for different kind of items.

**For me** the decrease operation could reduce the Quantity to 0 and then to remove the item. If, for an item, there are any requirements that specify any minimum quantity for the items in the basket then this requirements have to be checked before decrease operation the information could be sent to the decrease operation.

And we could compare the decrease/remove operations with add/increase operation. So, you could add item, you could increase its quantity with increase operation, but you could add again the same item but in the basket you will just increase the quantity of the item that is already there.

***How do you prefer to implement these operations? Do you know any restrictions which I have to re-think?***

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is - putting 0 in quantity should remove the item - because customers are going to put 0 in there and expect it to work! Do you want to give the customer an error message even though its very clear what they want to do? Ha - thats why all e-commerce programmers should work in retail first :-)

The second answer is - **it should be possible to update more then one item in the cart.** if i have 10 items in my cart, and i want to increase the quantity of 6 of them, and make 4 of them 0 quantity - i should be able to do that in one operation. i should be able to change the quantities - click update - and have them all change. (Related to this is checking inventory and pricing as part of a cart update operation.)

The third answer is -- when in doubt for any e-commerce question -- the answer is **how does amazon do it?** and amazon allows you to set 0 quantity for a cart item.